# Matching table between select in a function into a biggest select

Tags: sql, oracle

I have to call a `function` into a `select`, and at the same time, i have to do a `select` into that `function` which is matching with the biggest `select`.

I try this but it doesn't work:

```
SELECT field1,
       field2,
       function(select field3 from table2 where table2.id = table1.id and table2.id = 3)
  FROM table1
 WHERE ...
```

How should i do the select into the function?

Comment: Doesn't work how? How many columns do the sub-query return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do a Union of results as

```
SELECT field1,
       field2,
 FROM table1
 WHERE ...
Union All
Select function(select * from table2 where table2.id = table1.id) --function returning max
```

Comment: How can this work if the function returns a single column?

Comment: Function in example doesn't return a single column. Union All only works if all columns are matching.